# restrict user from entering nodejs server

Tags: node.js, authentication, server

I have setup a chatbot system by creating a nodejs server. so different users can use the chat system. i want to restrict certain users from using chat system when they are unauthenticated. Every time user connects nodejs server an authentication is performed. if it is authenticated then further conversation can be done in chat system. if not authenticated then user should not be able to start the conversation. how to restrict such users.

Comment: are you storing the authentication data somewhere, like a database?

Comment: yes through a text file

Comment: you haven't described your problem completely, but the best thing you can do in a chat system is to use socket.io, and they are having a npm package called socketio-auth. It is well documented and have a look into it